# How do I initialize a Dictionary(Of String, HashSet(Of String)) in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I've got an existing `String` and `HashSet(Of String)`, but the following code

```
Dim myDict As New Dictionary(Of String, HashSet(Of String))(myString, myHashSet)
```

yields this Intellisense error: `Argument matching parameter 'comparer' narrows from 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet(Of String)' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer(Of String)'`

What's the right way to create this dictionary?

Comment: Create it and then add the values...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [Collection Initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293617.aspx):

```
Dim myDict As New Dictionary(Of String, HashSet(Of String)) From 
       {{myString, myHashSet}}
```